# High CPU on akka.io.pinned-dispatcher on Windows

Tags: akka, cpu-usage, spray

**Problem** akka.io.pinned-dispatcher utilize 100% CPU on one core doing infinite loop selection on channel selector. 
Same problem can be faced when using Spray framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally workaround come from [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/lkckxb9NgWA).

Disable Windows connection closing detection is workaround to this problem.

```
akka {

  io {

    tcp {

      # On Windows connection aborts are not reliably detected unless an OP_READ is
      # registered on the selector _after_ the connection has been reset. This
      # workaround enables an OP_CONNECT which forces the abort to be visible on Windows.
      # Enabling this setting on other platforms than Windows will cause various failures
      # and undefined behavior.
      # Possible values of this key are on, off and auto where auto will enable the
      # workaround if Windows is detected automatically.

      windows-connection-abort-workaround-enabled = off
    }

  }

}
```